# For loop with nested 'with...end with'

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to use a -with...end with-
within a -for..next- loop. The idea is to get all these things on every sheet. Code below is pseudo

```
    For Sheet = Sheet1 to Sheet10
        With Sheet
            ...code
        End With
     Next
```

So I have 10 sheets. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc
What I can't seem to figure out is how to loop through all these sheets

Comment: Hello @Malachi , I always try to search first but most of the time I can't find anything eventhough there are answers that would help me. Do you have any suggestions on how to find exactly what I am looking for?

Comment: if you want a `VBA for each statement` type that into Google and ride the IntelliSense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should try this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918281/1214743

> ```
> Dim WS As Worksheet
> For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
>     ResizeColumns WS
> Next WS
> ```

You could create an array of the worksheet names and then foreach through them, if you don't want to select every Worksheet in the Workbook.

Comment: This will loop around all sheets, not sheet1 to sheet10? what happens if there is another sheet not meant to be processed?

Comment: OP Suggests "The idea is to get all these things on every sheet" when someone says that about Excel I tend to think they want all the sheets in the workbook.  but I will edit my answer @99moorem

Comment: @99moorem Then the OP can easily add an IF condition to ignore it.

Comment: @99moorem - What if there one or many sheets between 1-10 are deleted?

Comment: @Malachi Actually there are some sheets that need to be excluded but I will just put -if not WS = sheet to be excluded then.. -. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iIndex As Integer

For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
    Set ws = Worksheets(iIndex)
    ws.Activate

    'Do something here.
    ws.Range("A2").Value = "SomeValue"
Next iIndex
```

Comment: This will loop around all sheets, not sheet1 to sheet10? what happens if there is another sheet not meant to be processed?

Comment: Correct. It will loop all sheets. If you want to target sheets you will have to do For iIndex = 3 To 5 or whatever your range is.  The user stated "I have 10 sheets" and how to "loop through all these sheets".

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it does not work because Sheet will not be an object. The for each solutions below will give you a sheet object and allow you to use with.

```
Dim wks as Worksheet
For Each wks in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With wks
  ...
End With
Next
```

Should work

Comment: This is already an answer.

Comment: True, part of the answer was already there, but I included a explanation of why the original solution failed to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim wsTemp as Worksheet

For each wsTemp in Worksheets
   wsTemp.activate
   'Do something
Next wsTemp
```

Comment: This will loop around all sheets, not sheet1 to sheet10? what happens if there is another sheet not meant to be processed?

Comment: The user asked "So I have 10 sheets...how to loop through all of these sheets?"