# Find Text, Apply an outside border to that row, but only for the to Table Rows,

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will find the Text: "Homemade" in Column, and want to apply an Outside Border to that Row.  But how to apply the outside border to only the rows within the Table, not `.EntireRow`?

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Tbl     As ListObject
Dim Rng     As Range        ' range in which to set the table
Dim Rl      As Long         ' last row
Dim Cl      As Long         ' last column

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then

'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A3:M
     ' find the last used row in column A
     Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     ' find the last used column in row 3
     Cl = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     ' set the range for the table
     Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
     ' convert the range to a table
     Set Tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Rng, , xlYes)

Dim Homemade As Range

   Set Homemade = .Range("C:C").Find("HOMEMADE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

     With Homemade
       .EntireRow.BorderAround , xlThick, -11489280
     End With

   End If
  End With
 Next Ws
```

Comment: You could use `Intersect` - find the intersection of `Homemade.EntireRow` and the table.

Comment: Not related to your question, but to your code... it would be easier to read as a whole if the indention was better, such that the items contained within a `With` statement were indented another order than those not contained, same for those within the `For Each` statement..

Comment: If you have a known table width, you can set-up `.range(.cells(homemade.row,1),.cells(homemade.row,7))` for the `.borderaround`.

Comment: Assuming table starts from A:G (=7 columns) ou could also resize the found cell range in C:C by: `Homemade.Offset(Columnoffset:=-2).Resize(Columnsize:=7).BorderAround, xlThick, -11489280` where `Columnoffset:=-2` moves 2 cells to the left  
and `Columnsize:=7` indicates the total range columns count in your ListObject. Even shorter: `Homemade.Offset(0,-2).Resize(1,7).BorderAround , xlThick, -11489280` :-)

Comment: @T.M. Thank you.. For my understanding, why `.Resize(1,7)`?  If I want to keep it in the same row, my first thought would be: `Resize(0,7) to keep it in the same row..?   Also the Color did not change.

Comment: The 1st argument RowSize indicates the number of rows in the new range, therefore: `1`. (If this argument is omitted, the number of rows in the range remains the same, e.g. `Resize(,7)` ... c.f. [Range.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

Comment: @Cyril When trying to add the sytax you suggested.  It's not highlighting random rows.  Do i still use the `With Home` block?  I have `With Homemade             .Range(.Cells(Homemade.Row, 1), .Cells(Homemade.Row, 13)).BorderAround , xlThick, -11489280
            End With`

Comment: @T.M. thank you.  However, the border color does not change.  Why is that?

Comment: See MS Help [Range.BorderAround](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround) ... if you don't care for the argument order it's best to include the arguments variable name, e.g. `..., Color:=-11489280` :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky -- you need to establish a `ListObject` for the table, then determine which row your target text is in. The logic steps here are:

1. Find the target string
2. Determine if the target string is in the table
3. Determine the row in the table
4. Set a range for that row
5. Define your border for that range

I'm using a [very useful function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996123/4717755) I wrote to determine if a cell (any cell) is in a table. The test code for the example is here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Sheet1

    Dim targetText As String
    targetText = "HOMEMADE"

    With Ws
        Dim Homemade As Range
        Set Homemade = .Range("C:C").Find(targetText, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Homemade Is Nothing Then
            Dim tblName As String
            tblName = CellInTable(Homemade)
            If tblName <> vbNullString Then
                Dim theTable As ListObject
                Set theTable = .ListObjects(tblName)
                Dim homemadeRow As Long
                homemadeRow = Homemade.Row - theTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).Row + 1
                theTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(homemadeRow).BorderAround , _
                                                                 xlThick, -11489280
            Else
                '--- the cell with the targetText is not in a table
            End If
        Else
            '--- didn't find the targetText
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CellInTable(ByRef thisCell As Range) As String
    '--- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996123/4717755
    Dim tableName As String
    tableName = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    tableName = thisCell.ListObject.Name
    CellInTable = tableName
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a table already created.  I updated the Macro above. The table goes from Column A:M, and It will always have "Homemade" in Column C

Comment: My example is not creating a table, it's determining if the "HOMEMADE" string exists in a cell within a table. If you can guarantee your string will always be in the table, you only have to attach a `ListObject` to the table (as in my example) and calculate the table row number so you can get the range of that table row.